# How to access the elements in document.getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname, nodelist

Hello everyone and happy holidays. I hope your all staying warm and safe. Im here because I am having a little bit of an issue with some code. I'm not new to programming but am fairly new to JavaScript. I have searched for this questions answer and have found it on this site, but I seem to be having an issue anyway even after implementing the agreed upon solution. The TypeError being thrown points to the line where the 'var sections' variable is first used. That line simply appends the h1 element to the current div with 'class="section"'in the NodeList. The TypeError data says 'cannot read property appendChild of null' which means I don't have a proper reference to a node of type Element which I would need in order to use appendChild() or the style object. I'm just trying to figure out whats wrong with this but simply am at a loss. The answer I got on another thread here as to how you properly get a reference of the elements using getElementsByClassName() said that you simply use the 'item()' method of the NodeList object like so:

```
var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');
var section_header = document.createElement('h1');
sections.item(0).appendChild(section_header);
```

vs. what I was originally using...

```
var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');
var section_header = document.createElement('h1');
sections[0].appendChild(section_header);
```

... after I made the switch to the 'NodeList.item()' method I started getting the TypeError. The image attached is a screenshot of chrome dev tools, an instance of sublime and the page you can see open in the text editor is what you see open in chrome(a blank page with dark background). I'm only doing this to learn so its not for a project or anything. its just scratch pad code. I hope this post complies with the forums policies as I know an agreed upon answer is available but as you can see something is still wrong. Thank you everyone for your time and advice in advance it's greatly appreciated.

Here's the test code I am actually working with which is seen in the screenshot open in sublime. Just to throw out there, I did try moving the script tag itself around(e.g. in the head, under the body opening & above the body closing tag but still the error persisted:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="section">

            </div>
            <div class="section">

            </div>
            <div class="section">

            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Colors to be applied to each sections background.
            var colors = ['#455a64','#616161','#5d4037'];

            // The sections.
            var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');

            // The header tag to add to each section.
            var section_header = document.createElement('h1');

            // The count to be added to each sections title ex. <h1>Section Title #1.</h1>
            var section_count = 1;

            for(var index = 0; index <= colors.length; index++) {
                // The text to be added to each sections header.
                var section_header_txt = 'Section #' + section_count;
                // Add the text with the incremented section count to the sections h1 element.
                section_header.innerHTML = section_header_txt;
                // Append the section header to its new section parent.
                sections.item(index).appendChild(section_header); // This is where the TypeError is thrown. 
                // Add styles to each new section.
                sections.item(index).style.backgroundColor = colors[index].toString();
                sections.item(index).style.width = '100%';
                sections.item(index).style.height = '100vh';
                // Raise the section title count by 1.
                section_count++;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[screenshot of workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tVch.png)

Update:

As suggested below I changed the case operator from <= to just < but to no avail. I am still getting the same TypeError: cannot read property 'appendChild' of type null. Heres an a screenshot of the update and result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND28K.png)

Update to Dan's answer:

Screenshot below of the results from the changes suggested. I'm still getting this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpUBb.png)

Okay so I stripped away a bunch of the code and now it works. anything to do with the header element creation and appending is gone but i cant quite see the difference. Can anyone tell me from viewing this why it would work now. Strangely enough even though the background colors have been applied i still get the TypeError saying it can't read the style property?!?!

[Updated screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw410.png)

Comment: On the for loop change from `<=` to `<` so it loops 3 times instead of 4 which is what was makingthe error since there's no 4º item (section) to use the appendChild method on.

Comment: ahhh I think I tried that but let me try again. Thanks Ill get back with a screenshot of the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type error is caused by the incorrect `for` loop `condition`. `<= 4` will have the for loop execute on index `4`, which would return `undefined` for the `colors` array.

There are other issues with the code you posted as well.

1. The `section_header` element creation should be moved to inside the `for` loop. Otherwise, you will be rewriting the html of the same element and move it to the last section, resulting only the 3rd section having the section header text.
2. `GetElementsByClassname` returns an array of the elements. You can simply use the array index to refer to the elements, no need for `.item`
3. You already have access to an index variable, you can simply add 1 to that instead of have a `sectionCount` variable that increments manually.

```js
var colors = ['#455a64','#616161','#5d4037'];

// var sections is an array of  elements with 'section' as classname
var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');

for(var index = 0; index < colors.length; index++) {
  var section_header_txt = 'Section #' + ( index + 1 );
  
  // create a new section header element for each section
  var section_header = document.createElement('h1');
  section_header.innerHTML = section_header_txt;
  
  // instead of calling .item, just use array index
  sections[index].appendChild(section_header); 
  sections[index].style.backgroundColor = colors[index].toString();
  sections[index].style.height = '100vh';
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks man I guess I get a little OCD. I like to always have everything stored in variables "in case" I use it again but it is entirely uneccessary.

Answer (score 1):

your for loop is not good. "for(var index = 0; index <= colors.length; index++)"
You have 3 color items so your index should only increment when index is smaller then the colors.length.
So you need to check for index < colors.length in the for loop.
See below.

```
        for(var index = 0; index < colors.length; index++) {
            // The text to be added to each sections header.
            var section_header_txt = 'Section #' + section_count;
            // Add the text with the incremented section count to the sections h1 element.
            section_header.innerHTML = section_header_txt;
            // Append the section header to its new section parent.
            sections.item(index).appendChild(section_header); // This is where the TypeError is thrown. 
            // Add styles to each new section.
            sections.item(index).style.backgroundColor = colors[index].toString();
            sections.item(index).style.width = '100%';
            sections.item(index).style.height = '100vh';
            // Raise the section title count by 1.
            section_count++;
        }
```

Comment: Thank a lot for responding that was what I thought to do as well at some point but as you can see in the updated screenshot there is still this pesky TypeError. Everything seems sound and logical to me but.....?

Comment: @user8645420 I think you need to remove the + 1in var section_header_txt = 'Section #' + ( index + 1 ); so it should be var section_header_txt = 'Section #' + ( index );    Did you try my code ?

Comment: @user8645420 Also did you try to make the section_count start at 0 ? now you already start with 1.

Comment: hey user8645420 sorry yes I did try your code. I purposely added the (index + 1) in order for each sections header to be numbered properly. without the +1 on index the first sections header would be labled "section 0" since index is used to loop through an array it starts at 0.

Comment: look at my updated screen shot I got the code to work but i'm still getting the Error

Answer (score 0):

On the `for` loop change from `<=` to `<` on the condition so it only loops 3 times instead of 4. On the 4º loop it tries to use the method appendChild on the section number 4 (item index 4) which doesn't exist, creating the error.

```js
// Colors to be applied to each sections background.
var colors = ['#455a64','#616161','#5d4037'];

// The sections.
var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');

// The header tag to add to each section.
var section_header = document.createElement('h1');

// The count to be added to each sections title ex. <h1>Section Title #1.</h1>
var section_count = 1;

for(var index = 0; index < colors.length; index++) {
  // The text to be added to each sections header.
  var section_header_txt = 'Section #' + section_count;
  // Add the text with the incremented section count to the sections h1 element.
  section_header.innerHTML = section_header_txt;
  // Append the section header to its new section parent.
  sections.item(index).appendChild(section_header); // This is where the TypeError is thrown. 
  // Add styles to each new section.
  sections.item(index).style.backgroundColor = colors[index].toString();
  sections.item(index).style.width = '100%';
  sections.item(index).style.height = '100vh';
  // Raise the section title count by 1.
  section_count++;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys and gals the answer was to simply to re-arrange some lines as posted by Dan basically. 
1) I put the `document.createElement('h1')` inside of the for loop instead of above it. 
2) I switched to `document.createTextNode()` instead of using `Element.innerHTML`. 
3) As for using `document.getElementsByClassName('section')[0]` vs. `document.getElementsByClassName('section').item(0)`, I find that both work and produce the same result.

As you can see in the screenshot the code works now but strangely (at least to me) in the console I'm still getting the same TypeError saying that the style object could not be read.

[View of current work results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvBnn.png)

[View of the sources view of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMt3i.png)